# LibGDX - Accelerometer Problems

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, accelerometer

I got some issues. I'm using LibGDX.

1. When I hit an object, my Fighter is supposed to fall to the Ground. BUT, because of the Accelerometer, i can still move it up and down eventhough it died. The Scroller on the x-Axis though stops.
   **Question: (FIXED)** How can i make the Accelerometer stop, after Ive been hit, and make the Fighter accelerate to the ground (in absence of the accelerometer, all by itself) ?
2. When I move the Fighter up and down, the transition from "moving up" to "moving down" isnt smooth. It seems like it laggs.
   **Question:** How can I Increase the Sensitivity of my Accelerometer?
3. Also, When I tilt the Phone further, the velocity stay the same.
   **Question:** How can i increase the velocity, in relation to the tilt degree ?

Thank You !

The Codes are Below:

**Accelerometer Code:**

```
       float accelY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();



      if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() < 5){
         velocity.y = -40;
      }


      if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() > 5){
         velocity.y = 40;
      }
```

**When Fighter hits an Object and dies:**

```
              public void die() {
      isAlive = false;
      velocity.y = 0;
      acceleration.y = 460;
   }
```

Comment: Regarding first question, just put an `if (isAlive)` block around your code that changes the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

**You Need to wrap the accel. function with the Alive variable**

```
if(isAlive)
{
    if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() < 5)
    {
        velocity.y = -40;
    }

    if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() > 5)
    {
        velocity.y = 40;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Q2,

```
if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() < 5){
    velocity.y = -40;
}


if (Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() > 5){
    velocity.y = 40;
}
```

The reason it's not smooth is because you did not interpolate the movement.
One workaround is:

```
if (Math.abs(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY()) > 5){
    YFactor = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
}
```

//somewhere in your game loop

```
if(YFactor >0)
{
    if(velocity.y) < YFactor*8{ //tweak this value
        velocity.y += YFactor; //tweak this value
    }
}
else
{
    //reverse above logic
}
```

What this does is that it will keep - the velocity or +, up until YFactor * 8 (which is what your Q3 needs)

This is just an introduction of concept, you'll need to handle the scope of the variables.